# Is there a way to parse data generated by perf tool?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, profiler, perf

I have some profiling data generated by linux-perf tool, Is there some quick way to parse it and use it as utf-8 data inside a python3 script?

tried the following all I get is the warning

```
data = open('stage.data','rb')

def hex_to_utf8(hex_data):
  """
  Converts a hexadecimal string or bytes representing hex data to a UTF-8 encoded string.

  Args:
      hex_data: The hexadecimal data to be converted. Can be a string or bytes.

  Returns:
      A string containing the decoded UTF-8 text, or None if decoding fails.

  Raises:
      ValueError: If the input data is not valid hexadecimal.
  """

  # Validate input data
  if isinstance(hex_data, str):
    try:
      hex_data = bytes.fromhex(hex_data)
    except ValueError:
      raise ValueError("Invalid hexadecimal string")

  # Attempt UTF-8 decoding
  try:
    return hex_data.decode("utf-8")
  except UnicodeDecodeError:
    # Handle potential non-UTF-8 data
    print("Warning: Data is not valid UTF-8 encoded text.")
    return None


for line in data:
    print(hex_to_utf8(line))
```

Comment: `perf stat --field-separator SEP` makes the output easy to parse CSV-style.  And `--no-big-num` omits thousands separators from big numbers.  But there are many tools that output stuff other than `perf stat`, and you haven't said what you're parsing or what `perf` output you want to get into a Python data structure.

Comment: this is how I want it to be parsed in simple text tokens 
    ```<per>%  <bmk>  <bmk_dir>  [.] <source_func>```